# Action of CommandLink/CommandButton in p:treeTable is not invoked

Tags: primefaces, treetable

I download primefaces 3.1, add to my project tried to add a commandButton/commandLink into a column of a treeTable
but action of commandButton/commandLink in a column is not invoked except the root row.

What may the problem be? Thanks

**EDIT:**

treeTable in xhtml:

```
<p:treeTable var="catalog" value="#{catalogSelectBean.root}" lazy="true" selection="#{catalogSelectBean.selectedNode}" selectionMode="single">
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Katalog Name" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{catalog.name}" />
    </p:column>

  <p:column width="100">
    <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="Katalog Desc"/>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{catalog.description}"/>
  </p:column>

  <p:column>
  <p:commandButton action="#{formProductRelationView.updateProductListForSelectedCatalog()}"
                                                update=":main_form:selectProductTable"
        value="Bring Products">
    </p:commandButton>
    </p:column>
</p:treeTable>
```

Bean:

```
@Component("catalogSelectBean")
@Scope("request")
public class CatalogSelectBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Autowired
    private CatalogService catalogService;
    private TreeNode root;
    private TreeNode selectedNode;  


    private DualListModel<Catalog> pickListCatalogs;


    public TreeNode getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    public TreeNode getSelectedNode() {
        return selectedNode;
    }

    public void setSelectedNode(TreeNode selectedNode) {
        this.selectedNode = selectedNode;
    }

    public void onNodeSelect(NodeSelectEvent event) {
        Catalog g = (Catalog)event.getTreeNode().getData();
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Selected", g.getName());
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
    }

    public CatalogSelectBean() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void unLoad(){

        createRoot();
        createPickListModel();
    }


    private void createPickListModel() {
        //Players  
        List<Catalog> source = catalogService.loadChilds(catalogService.getRootCatalog());
        List<Catalog> target = new ArrayList<Catalog>();  

        pickListCatalogs = new DualListModel<Catalog>(source, target);  

    }

    private void createRoot() {
        Catalog g = null ;

            g = catalogService.getRootCatalog();

        root = new DefaultTreeNode("Root", null);

        TreeNode caRoot = new DefaultTreeNode(g,root);
        generateTree(caRoot,g);

    }

    private void generateTree(TreeNode subRoot, Catalog g) {

        for(Catalog p : g.getChildCatalogs()){
            TreeNode node0 = new DefaultTreeNode(p,subRoot);
            if(p.getChildCatalogs()!= null && p.getChildCatalogs().size()>0)
                generateTree(node0, p);
        }
    }

    public void resetTree() {
        root.setSelected(false);
    }



    public DualListModel<Catalog> getPickListCatalogs() {
        return pickListCatalogs;
    }



}
```

Also i have a formProductRelationView bean which has the updateProductListForSelectedCatalog() method.

Thanks for attention.

Comment: With the info you've provided, only god knows.

Comment: I gave up my stubbornness to add commandlink in every row. I am trying to add selection to treetable and select with a button that is out of treeTable. Thanks